# Generate sequence of random numbers with defined proximity

Tags: distributions, correlation, sampling, random-generation

I need to generate a sequence of random numbers in some range (for example [0; 30,000,000]). There is an additional condition:

- About 85% of numbers must have a neighbour in distance not greater than 4,000
- About 5% of numbers must not have a neighbour in distance 4,000
- About 5% of numbers must be from a subsequences of 3 numbers where neigbours are at distance 4,000
- About 5% of numbers must be from a subsequences of 4 and greater numbers where neigbours are at distance 4,000

What is the best way to generate the sequence?

---

Look like I should provide some details to clarify the nature of the problem.

The generated sequence should be used as testing data for some service (online taxi). I need to perform certain analysis of events per year (30,000,000 ≈ 60 * 60 * 24 * 365). Session is a set of events where neghbour events differ less the an hour (4,000 ≈ 60 * 60). If the event has not a neighbour in hour range, than this event is out of any session. So, I need a sequence with largest share of sessions of two events. Some share of out-of-session events. And some share of sessions with multiple events. Actually, these params 85%-5%-5%-5% is an approximate distribution that make sense rather than strict condition.
So,

- two-events session is a normal taxi ride (start,finish)
- multiple events session is a composite taxi ride
- separated events are cancelled rides

I would like to have a sequence to model this situation. 
For example, I could try to experiment with uniform distribution to obtain an acceptable sequence. However, it does not look believable.

Comment: There are so many restrictions that calling a sequence of such numbers "random" would seem to be unjustified.  Could you explain the intended purpose of this sequence?  That might help people formulate effective answers.

Comment: @whuber - Thank you. I will expand the question

Comment: This sounds like some sort of class assignment in a programming course. If so, please add the self-study tag and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Peter this question is far too vague for that.  Please take care not to close threads as "self study" unless you have a good basis to know it's a routine textbook question.

Comment: (1) How many 'random' numbers in the whole sequence? (b) Couldn't some of the bulleted events in the 2nd list occur concurrently? E.g. A cancelled ride for one taxi occurs while another 2-event ride is in progress? (Or is everything for a single taxi.)

Answer (score 0):

**Speculative comment:** Single-taxi model. Simulate hour by hour. Even if
this is totally wrong, your reasons explaining why might be helpful.

Each hour has the following numbers X (0 through 6) of events with probability p.

```
x   p
0   .5     # inactivity (perhaps too likely)
1   .025   # cancelled
2   .425   # normal taxi ride
3   .025   # three event ride
4   .015   # etc.
5   .008
6   .002
```

Within each one-hour interval (in sequence) generate the appropriate
number of events (sorted in order) according to a uniform distribution
within the hour. If the probabilities of non-0 hours are multiplied by 2
they approximate your 5%, 85%, etc. A fresh kind of taxi ride starts
at the beginning of each hour.

Example: Simulate 20 hours in R:

```
m = 20;  x = c()
for (i in 1:20){
  n = sample(0:6, 1, prob=c(.5,.025,.425,.025,.015,.008,.002))
  x = c(x, i+round(sort(runif(n)),2)) }
x
 [1]  1.74  1.97  5.24  5.63  7.14  7.29  9.14  9.36 10.16 10.69
[11] 10.77 11.40 11.57 13.25 13.39 14.30 14.40 16.31 16.59 18.28
[21] 18.45 18.46 18.59 18.61 19.23 19.79
```

Another 20 hours:

```
 [1]  3.40  3.41  5.20  5.74  7.37  7.56  7.57  8.36  8.50 10.34
[11] 10.62 10.64 10.73 12.37 12.98 13.21 13.57 16.94 16.94 18.13
[21] 18.61 20.06 20.13
```